# How to clear the certificate cache in Universal Windows Platform apps?

Tags: c#, c++, ssl, uwp

Application data for UWP apps are stored in C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\[package_id]

The subfolder AC\Microsoft\CryptnetFlushCache\MetaData appears to contain a record of websites accessed securely via an HttpClient. Research indicates that this folder and its siblings are a cache for SSL/TLS.

How can this cache be cleared from within my own program?

Answer (score 1):

In UWP app, there is API related to `ApplicationData`, for example [`ApplicationData.ClearAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.clearasync.aspx) method, but it can only removes all application data from the local, roaming, and temporary app data stores.

We can use [`Directory.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) method to delete this AC folder.

For example:

```
public static void Clean()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder localDirectory = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string path = localDirectory.Path;
        path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\")) + @"\AC\Microsoft\CryptnetFlushCache\MetaData";
        Directory.Delete(path, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR CLEANING CACHE: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But there is no document to describe the detailed files stored in this folder, so this may cause unexpected behavior/result in your app.

Comment: Certificates brought in with CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync appear to be saved to to path.LastIndexOf("\\")) + @"\AC\Microsoft\SystemCertificates"